# Waypoints - add class to this not working (pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the Waypoints javascript plugin (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) in a project in to identify when certain elements scroll into viewport. You can see my project here: http://thomasgrist.co.uk/portfolio2017/work.html

As each Waypoint scrolls I'm trying to add a class.

I'm not using JQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="projects" class="dragscroll">

    <div id="project1" class="projects">
        <div id="clientTypeTopContainer">
            <div id="clientTypeTop">MASTERCARD</div>
        </div>
        <img data-original="img/project1.jpg" id="project1Image" class="projectImage">
        <div id="project2Title" class="projectTitle">Advanced New Passat<br/>campaign site</div>
    </div>

    <div id="project2" class="projects">
        <div id="clientTypeTopContainer" class="clientTypeTopContainerBottom">
            <div id="clientTypeTop">MASTERCARD</div>
        </div>
        <img data-original="img/project2.jpg" id="project2Image" class="projectImage">
        <div id="project2Title" class="projectTitle">Advanced New Passat<br/>campaign site</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var continuousElements = document.getElementsByClassName('projects')

for (var i = 0; i < continuousElements.length; i++) {
    new Waypoint({
        element: continuousElements[i],
        handler: function() {
            //alert('helloworld'),
            this.disable(),
            this.className +=' projectFadeIn';
        },
        context: document.getElementById('projects'),
        horizontal: true
    })
}
```

I think this is the past not working:

```
this.className +=' projectFadeIn';
```

When I get an element by ID I can add a class, but not when I prefer to it as 'this' which I need to.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.
Thomas.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the manual](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) use `this.element` to target the dom element

Comment: Do you mean this.element.className +=' projectFadeIn';   ?

Comment: This is applying the class to the first div in the container instead of the div that is currently scrolling into viewport. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah it add the class to `div.projects`, correct? Which element did you want to target?

Comment: Yes correct. There is a container with an ID that is projects . That container has several divs in it, each with a class that is also projects. this.element is adding the class to the 1st div in the container. I'm looking to target the element that is currently scrolling into viewport based on it's size. For example on an average desktop display this is likely to be the 2nd or 3rd div.

Comment: I was aware of the elements you're targeting, but thought you wanted to target a child element. I think you missed that when you continue to scroll it will add class to the next one, etc. You probably need to add `offset: 'right-in-view'` as explained [here](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, these comments sent me in the right direction